# Swift UDP NWListener issue

Tags: ios, swift, networking, udp

I am working with Network framework to achieve UDP transfer. Right now I've successfully connected my application with one device (the device, in which we send the data through UDP connection and receive data from that device and display in the application), and data send/receive is working properly.

I have two device. But my issue is that, when I tried to connect with another device the data is sent to the device but I was not receive the data. My listener is not working with another device. I've tried with re-installing the app, then also not working.

And when I tried to connect with the first device again then it's working properly.

So, is there any issue in my NWConnection or NWListener ? Because it seems that the code which I wrote is only allow me to connect with one device.

Here, below I attached my code for UDP connection for your reference.

Please anyone that will solve my issue would be so grateful to me.

Thank you in advance..!!

```
import Foundation
import Network
import UIKit

protocol UDPListener: class {
     func handleResponse(_ client: UDPConnection, data: Data)
     func errorWhileSending(_ client: UDPConnection)
}

class UDPConnection: UIViewController {
    
    var connection: NWConnection?
    var listner: NWListener?
    weak var delegate: UDPListener?
        
    let parameters = NWParameters.udp
    var singleton = Singleton.shared
    
    // for connect with device
    func connect(withHost: NWEndpoint.Host, port: NWEndpoint.Port) {
        parameters.allowLocalEndpointReuse = true
        
        self.connection = NWConnection(host: withHost, port: port, using: parameters)
        self.connection?.stateUpdateHandler = { (newState) in
            switch (newState) {
            case .ready:
                print("connection ready")
            case .setup:
                print("connectionsetup")
            case .cancelled:
                print("connectioncancelled")
            case .preparing:
                print("connection Preparing")
            default:
                print("connection waiting or failed")
                
            }
        }
        self.connection?.start(queue: .main)
    }
    
    // for sending UDP string
    func sendUDP(_ content: String) {
        let contentToSendUDP = content.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        self.connection?.send(content: contentToSendUDP, completion: NWConnection.SendCompletion.contentProcessed(({ (NWError) in
            if (NWError == nil) {
                print("Data was sent to UDP")
            } else {
                print("ERROR SEND! Error when data (Type: Data) sending. NWError: \n \(NWError!)")
                self.delegate?.errorWhileSending(self)
            }
        })))
    }
    
    //for sending UDP data
    func sendUDP(_ content: Data) {
        self.connection?.send(content: content, completion: NWConnection.SendCompletion.contentProcessed(({ (NWError) in
            if (NWError == nil) {
                print("Data was sent to UDP")
                //self.receiveUDP()
            } else {
                print("ERROR Send! Error when data (Type: Data) sending. NWError: \n \(NWError!)")
                self.delegate?.errorWhileSending(self)
            }
        })))
    }
    
    //////////////// UDP LISTNER /////////////////////

    func listenUDP(port: NWEndpoint.Port) {
        do {
            parameters.allowLocalEndpointReuse = true
            
            self.listner = try NWListener(using: parameters, on: port)
            self.listner?.stateUpdateHandler = {(newState) in
                switch newState {
                case .ready:
                    print("Listner ready")
                case .failed:
                    print("Listner failed")
                case .cancelled:
                    print("Listner cancelled")
                default:
                    break
                }
            }
            self.listner?.newConnectionHandler = {(newConnection) in
                newConnection.stateUpdateHandler = {newState in
                    switch newState {
                    case .ready:
                        print("new connection establish")
                        self.receive(on: newConnection)
                    case .failed:
                        print("new connection failed")
                    case .cancelled:
                        print("new connection cancelled")
                    default:
                        break
                    }
                }
                newConnection.start(queue: DispatchQueue(label: "new client"))
            }
        } catch {
            print("unable to create listener")
        }
        self.listner?.start(queue: .main)
    }
    
    func receive(on connection: NWConnection) {
        connection.receiveMessage { (data, context, isComplete, error) in
            if !isComplete {
                print("Not Complete")
            }
            if let error = error {
                print("Error in REceive: - ",error)
                return
            }
            if let data = data, !data.isEmpty {
                print("Data receive in UDPConenction;")
                guard self.delegate != nil else {
                        print("Error Receive: UDPClient response handler is nil")
                        return
                 }
                  self.delegate?.handleResponse(self, data: data)
            }
            self.receive(on: connection)
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: As soon as I see a property `connection` which is a single value I know you are going to have a problem with multiple devices - How can you keep track of multiple connections?. You need an array of connections. Also the code shown doesn't do anything with the listener, it seems to make outbound connections.

Comment: @Paulw11 I've edited the connection file. Sorry for the previous block of code. In the edited code I've mentioned about the listener.

Comment: I put your code into test app and made multiple connections without any problems.  You can test with a Mac or other unix box terminal using `nc -u <ipAddress> <port>` and whatever you type on the terminal will be sent to your app.  This is how I tested. Maybe you have a problem with the second device?